# Strange Push method for Single Linked List

Tags: python, data-structures

This is out of Zed Shaws "Learn More Python The Hard Way"
Specifically how this push method adds the next node to "self.begin.next" in the else block when self.begin and self.begin.next are never referenced.

```
class singleLinkedList(object):
  def init(self):
    self.begin = None
    self.end = None

def push(self, val): 
    curNode = Node(val, None)

    if self.begin is None: #I understand how this starts the node chain.
        self.end = curNode
        self.begin = self.end
    else:                  #But how is this else statement appending the nodes to self.begin.next?
        self.end.next = curNode 
        self.end = curNode
```

Comment: What makes you think a node is added as ``self.begin.next`` in the ``else`` clause? It very clearly adds one to ``self.end.next``. Are you wondering about a case with only one node in the list?

Comment: when you are creating the very first entry the currentNode is assigned to self.end which is further assigned to self.begin. So at this state the end and begin are same. Now when you add the second when you make  a self.end.next = curNode this aso updates the begin.next as both are same..and just after than you update the end to current node. So now end is at current node. Begin is at first node bu its next is linked to second node you inserted.

Answer (score 1):

when you are creating the very first entry the currentNode is assigned to self.end which is further assigned to self.begin. So at this state the end and begin are same. Now when you add the second when you make a self.end.next = curNode this aso updates the begin.next as both are same..and just after than you update the end to current node. So now end is at current node. Begin is at first node and its next is linked to second node you inserted.

```
> first insertion  
begin = firstNode 
end = firstNode 

> //Notice begin and end refer to same pointer
  
second insertion 
   end.next = secondNode
   (this also make begin.next = secondNode) as both were same new_end =
   secondNode // but this time begin is not same as new node 
         
> so when you insert the thirdNode 
  old_second_end.next = thirdNode
  new_end = thirdNode
```